# Draw Size in Inch

Tags: android

I would like to draw a shape 1cm big, but I only know how to set the size in pixel.

```
canvas.drawRect(0,0,10,10,paint);
```

Is it possible to set the size in cm or inch?
Or maybe to get the dpi of the screen?

Comment: you'd HAVE to get the dpi of the screen. that's the only way you could convert between pixels to "real" sizes.

Comment: Unfortunately, don't expect to be able to do this accurately: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=zh&fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/g56jV0Hora0

Answer (score 1):

You can define the size you want in the `res/values/dimens.xml` file, like:

```
<dimen name="your_value">10mm</dimen>
```

Then you can get this dimen in yout activity class:

`int value = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.your_value)`.

The value can be defined in inches too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "mm" or "in" dimension value in XML for millimeters/inches, respectively.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)